# tableView will display cell blocks main view

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I was trying to add some animations to my tableview cell and ended up using something like this. But it blocks my main thread. There is a delay of 1 second. How do I get it to work without blocking my main thread.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            cell.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

Any fix?

Comment: try Duration 0 it's work

Comment: Did you try removing the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block?

Comment: @BadhanGanesh yes i did try by removing the block. It did not work.

Comment: @SagarBhut if i reduce duration to 0, there will be no animation. Whats the point of the code in the first place then??

Comment: when you set duration 0 then your view controller load that time also that cell alpha set 1.0 so in that case controller load that time animation is done but that time view controller is load so animation not display